# Understanding legacy grails code?

Tags: unit-testing, grails

The following is a chunk of code in setUp method of controller unit test class in grails. I am trying to understand the purpose of the following setup code. The application has a TimeService which is responsible for doing time operations. I appreciate any help!

```
def customPropertyEditor = new CustomPropertyEditorRegistrar(timeService: new TimeService())

def map = (Map<String, PropertyEditorRegistrar>) servletContext.getAttribute(GrailsDataBinder.PROPERTY_EDITOR_REGISTRARS)
        if (!map) servletContext.setAttribute(GrailsDataBinder.PROPERTY_EDITOR_REGISTRARS, [customPropertyEditor: customPropertyEditor])
        else map.put('customPropertyEditor', customPropertyEditor)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i found that this chunk of code is responsible for making it so that date binds well. Apparently, there is no clean method to bind date in grails 2.2.

Answer (score 1):

Create this TimeService object that is `customPropertyEditor`

```
def customPropertyEditor = new CustomPropertyEditorRegistrar(timeService: new TimeService())
```

Make a map out of `servletContext.getAttribute(GrailsDataBinder.PROPERTY_EDITOR_REGISTRARS`

```
def map = (Map<String, PropertyEditorRegistrar>) servletContext.getAttribute(GrailsDataBinder.PROPERTY_EDITOR_REGISTRARS)
```

`if (!map)` =  If no map found = as in null due to no results

Then set `servletContext.setAttribute(GrailsDataBinder.PROPERTY_EDITOR_REGISTRARS` to be the object at the top `customPropertyEditor`

```
servletContext.setAttribute(GrailsDataBinder.PROPERTY_EDITOR_REGISTRARS, [customPropertyEditor: customPropertyEditor])
```

If there was a map put in the map customPropertyEditor this value

```
    else map.put('customPropertyEditor', customPropertyEditor)
```

As for what `GrailsDataBinder` is doing as `Servlet` `Attribute` have a search for it in the code base to see what other things are interacting